# AS3 cannot assign variable to child swf

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 SWFs. One Parent.swf and other is child.swf.

in the parent SWF I am loading child swf.

I am using a loader to load swf.  My code is as follows :

```
----------------------------------------
    stop();
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("stalla.swf");

var _loader = new Loader();
var stallaloader1:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
addChild(stallaloader1);

  Object(this).stallaloader1.x=5000;
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
_loader.load( req ); 
stallaloader1.addChild(_loader);
trace(stallaloader1.x);
//_loader.vipin="Ashwini n Meha";
function loader_complete(evt:Event):void {
//addChild(_loader);
var _loader:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.target.content);
    //addChild(_loader); //embedSWF
    //stallaloader1.stallclick;
    //_loader.stallclick;

    //evt.currentTarget.x=1000;

    // btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,_loader.stallclick);
     btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {videovariables(2)});

}
function videovariables(vid):void {
trace(_loader.vipin);
    _loader.vipin="Overwrite with Ashwini"
     trace(_loader.vipin);
 }
```

---

These 3 line work well if called in loader_complete, BUT

If we put them in videovariables function, we get error :

ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property vipin not found on flash.display.Loader and there is no default value.
    at _3dstalls_fla::Symbol1_1/videovariables()[_3dstalls_fla.Symbol1_1::frame1:53]
    at Function/()[_3dstalls_fla.Symbol1_1::frame1:49]

What may be the reason? Please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the error message it says : Property vipin not found on **flash.display.Loader**
meaning that _loader refers to the Loader instance, not to the MovieClip.

As the MovieClip you want is loaded in the loader (`_loader`), you can access it with `content` property of the Loader class.

```
function videovariables(vid):void {
     trace(_loader.content.vipin);
    _loader.content.vipin="Overwrite with Ashwini"
}
```